# javascript "this" failed to target

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

What am I doing wrong on the first example? It's not targetting the span and applying the background color. But the second example works great

1st.

```
    if($(".done").length > 0) {
        $(this).css("background","red");
    }
```

2nd.

```
    if($(".done").length > 0) {
        $(".done").css("background","red");
    }
```

Comment: you need to show more code. We can't read your mind.

Comment: show us the html plus the whole function

Comment: Good article on `this` in JS: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Comment: Are you expecting that `this` should be set to the result of the last jQuery?

Comment: @James: that is a good article, but the OP is confused with `this` in  a very specific context. I think Marek got it right, the OP is confused with jQuery event handlers or loops that set `this` to the jQuery object in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `this` value is not affected by merely running a selector through jQuery.  In fact, you can't change the `this` value at all within the confines of a particular function.

You could try this:

```
if($(".done").length > 0) {
    $('done').each(function() { $(this).css("background","red"); });
}
```

Best to cache the `$(".done")` thing of course. In this case, if that's really all the code that's there, there's no reason to do the test on the length anyway.

Comment: i think you don't even need that `if` condition

Comment: No need of the if condition, nor the `.each` method call.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov yes of course, but the original question sort-of demanded the explanation of why `this` wasn't set.  In the larger sense you're right - just `$('.done').css('background', 'red');` is all that's needed.

Comment: Ty @Pointy, actually my problem was that I was using "this" for an if statement wich is wrong. Marek had a good answer but he edited it.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` scope is available in functions iterating though list of objects

such as `.each()`,`.exists()` and so on, not in simple `if/else` condition

what should work is this:

```
$(".done").each(function(){
    $(this).css("background","red");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply replace your entire `if` condition with:

```
$(".done").css("background", "red");
```

If no elements match your CSS selector will return an empty array and nothing will happen. And if there are matching elements, a red background color will be applied to all of them.

As far as your question about the `this` variable is concerned, it is usually available inside  anonymous callbacks but not inside an `if` condition.

Comment: ty but I was looking for deleting the element if it was found, the css is just to see if it was targetted correctly

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to, and targets, the currently selected object/element. Your `if` statement doesn't select anything:

```
if($(".done").length > 0) { // tests if $('.done') exists, but doesn't select the objects.
    // therefore the 'this' doesn't target/refer to anything
    $(this).css("background","red");
}
```

Try instead:

```
if ($('.done').length) {
    $('.done').css('background-color','red');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Gm7Yy/).

It's worth noting that while the `if` tests for the existence of the objects returned by the `$('.done')` selector, if you omit the `if` test, and the selector doesn't match anything, jQuery won't throw an error, it'll simply perform no action ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Gm7Yy/1/)).

In this particular case it's not that hard to use plain JavaScript to achieve the same results:

```
var doneClassElem = document.getElementsByClassName('done');

for (i=0; i<doneClassElem.length; i++){
    doneClassElem[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Gm7Yy/2/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery only binds to this in a callback, but you aren't using callbacks here at all.

```
$('.done').click(function() {
  $(this).hide()
});
```

A common way to prevent calling the `$()` function over an over in code liek this is to cache the result to a local var.

```
var $done = $('.done')
if ($done.length > 0) {
  $done.css('background', 'red');
}
```

---

Somewhat unrelated, but you don't need to do that `length` check.  Even when a jQuery selector matches zero items, you can safely call other jQuery methods on that set without an errors.

Also, you should be using css classes here, rather then editing the style inline like this.  Then use `addClass()` to make it the class that has your red color int he stylesheet.

Then all this code becomes quite simply just:

```
$('.done').addClass('myClassThatMakesItRed');
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the whole of your code then it wont work because `this` will be the global object, which is probably window in the browser.

When you bind to an event with jQuery the event handler function has its context changed so that this referes to the element on which the event was triggered.

Your code could be better expressed as

```
$(".done").css("background", "red")
```

Since you don't really need to check if there are any elements that match.

Answer (score 0):

It's ambigous what *this* is in your first example. Note that *this* is the calling context of whatever function that is part of. If you were to use that code sniplette inside a event handler in jQuery than it would work.

Example:

```
// won't work
function red() { 
    // this = window -- in this case
    $(this).css("background","red");
}
red();

// works
$(".done").click(function() {
    // this = $(".done") -- set by jQuery
    $(this).css("background","blue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What `this` is isn't affected by `if` statements. Writing the same code as you have but in a different way might make this clearer for you.

You code was:

```
if($(".done").length > 0) {
  $(this).css("background","red");
}
```

You expected that `this` referred to the array of `$(".done")`. The following is semantically exactly the same:

```
var l = $(".done").length;
var z = 0;
if(z < l) {
  $(this).css("background","red");
}
```

What does `this` refer to in that example?

In both examples, `this` refers to the same thing: probably the `window` object of the HTML page. You see, `this` refers to the parent object of the function your code is running within.

Try the following:

```
<script>

    alert(this == window); // true

    function function1(){
        alert(this == window); // true
    }
    function1();


    // now let's create our own instance of an object

    var myObject = new Object();

    myObject.method1 = function(){
        alert(this == myObject); // true
    }

    myObject.method1();

</script>
```

Hope this helps.